# Proper way to insert Retrofit data to Room and display it using ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room, dagger-hilt

What would be the proper (best practice) way to get data from a Retrofit api, insert it into a Room database, and display the data from Room in the Viewmodel? Should the operation of inserting the data from Retrofit to Room happen in the repository or another class? How should the Room data be returned to the viewmodel?

As of right now my code fetches data using Retrofit <- repository <- ViewModel <- Fragment
-- Using Hilt for di. Also using the same data class for Retrofit and Room entity

Any advice or implementation suggestions are appreciated

Repository:

```
class ItemRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: ShopraApi
) {
    suspend fun getItems() = api.getUserItemFeed()
}
```

Api:

```
interface ShopraApi {

companion object {
    const val BASE_URL = "-"
}
    @GET("getUserItemFeed.php?user_id=1")
    suspend fun getUserItemFeed() : List<Item>
}
```

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ItemViewModel @Inject constructor(
    itemRepository: ItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val itemsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()
    val items: LiveData<List<Item>> = itemsLiveData

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            itemsLiveData.value = itemRepository.getItems()
        }
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "item_table")
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @NonNull
    val listing_id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val description: String
)
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
    fun getItemsFromRoom(): LiveData<List<Item>>

    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(item: Item)

    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertAllItems(itemRoomList: List<Item>)
}
```

ItemDatabase:

```
@Database(entities = [Item::class],version = 1)
abstract class ItemDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun itemDao() : ItemDao
}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ShopraApi.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideShopraApi(retrofit: Retrofit): ShopraApi {
        return retrofit.create(ShopraApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(app: Application) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(app, ItemDatabase::class.java, "item_database")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()

    @Provides
    fun provideTaskDao(db: ItemDatabase) = db.itemDao()
}
```

EDIT Updated Repository:

```
class ItemRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: ShopraApi,
    private val itemDao: ItemDao
) {
    fun loadItems(): LiveData<List<Item>> {
        return liveData{
            val getItems = api.getUserItemFeed()

            Log.e("ItemRepository","The size of the item list is 
${getItems.size}")

            getItems.forEach {
                item -> itemDao.insert(item)
            }
            val loadFromRoom = itemDao.getItemsFromRoom()

            emitSource(loadFromRoom)
       }
    }
}
```

Updated ItemViewModel:

```
class ItemViewModel @Inject constructor(
     itemRepository: ItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val items: LiveData<List<Item>> = itemRepository.loadItems()
}
```

I then call this code in my fragment

```
viewModel.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { items ->
        itemAdapter.submitList(items)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this in **Repository** and Repository is the "single source of truth" this is where you make the decision, when you get the data from network and save into localDB and load/expose from the localDB which is going to be the **room persistence**
You can use the utility class known as **Network Bound Resource** and there are alot implementation of network bound resource, this one is from official sample [google's sample of network bound resource](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide),
which is generic type abstract class use for this specific purpose but if you still wanna do it in the custom way, here is what you need to do.
1-> Make the network call and get the data from network and this data you are not going to expose to viewmodel
2-> once you receive the data insert into the localDB.
3-> Load or Expose your data from localDB to the viewmodel

**Code Sample:**

```
class ItemRepo(
    val dao: Dao,
    val api: Api
) {
    fun loadItems(): LiveData<List<Item>> {
        return liveData {

            // get from network
            val getFromNetwork = api.getList()

            // save into local
            getFromNetwork.forEach{
                item ->
                dao.insertItem(item)
            }

            //load from local
            val loadFromLocal = dao.getAllItem()
            
            emitSource(loadFromLocal)
        }
    }
}
```

You are gonna `Inject` Repository in  the viewmodel and from there data will observed by view, with that you are only gonna get the data from localDB.
Note: *This is just a sample you can further reuse it according to your use case for instance error handling, network handling like when network is not available or when you encounter the error what you should do.. things like that.*

Comment: I implemented your code. For some reason when the list is displayed in ViewPager2 from the fragment, it only shows 1 item. The first item in the list. I checked the size of the list returned by Retrofit in repository and it is 23 which is the correct size. I think it has to do with my ViewModel. I am unsure how to handle the LiveData<List<Item>> that is returned by the repository. Any idea why it only shows 1 item in the viewpager instead of 23 which retrofit api returns? I added my updated code to the question. Thank you

Comment: ``log`` from the view where you are observing, check out how many items you are getting from there.. and also give a look to your viewpager code

Comment: I know this is late. I fixed the issue a while ago and I believe it had to do with the Item Comparator I was using with my Adapter. The DiffUtil.ItemCallback areItemsTheSame() function was comparing values on the oldItem and the newItem that were the same. Since the values were the same the adapter thinks it is the same item and does not show the new item in the list. I changed the code to compare the primaryKey values of the two items and it worked. Just writing this in case someone else has the same issue.